# Custom CursorAdapter to click inside list-item-view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I've successfully managed to extend a CursorAdapter and change the bindView- and newView-methods to be able to have clickable buttons inside my list. The button (which actually is a clickable ImageView) uses a selector as a backgroundresource, and everything works fine except that when I click the list-item-view, the selector of the button/imageview is activated and hence it appears as if I clicked the button/imageview even though I didn't. The method inside the onclicklistener that's bound to the button/imageview though, is not activated when clicking the list-item-view, so that works properly, it's only the selector. Here is my CustomCursorAdapter:

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
    super(context, cursor, flags);
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context c, Cursor cursor){
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    final Context context = c;

    final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    final String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("number"));
    final String mail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mail"));

    holder.getTvName().setText(name);
    holder.getTvNumber().setText(number);
    holder.getTvMail().setText(mail);

    int row_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    holder.getCallButton().setTag(row_id);
    holder.getCallButton().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("Call " + name + "?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String uri = "tel:" + nummer.trim();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            builder.create().show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.setCallButton((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bCall));
    holder.setTvName((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName));
    holder.setTvNumber((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNumber));
    holder.setTvMail((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMail));
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {

    private TextView tvName, tvNumber, tvMail;
    private ImageView bCall;

    public ImageView getCallButton() {
        return bCall;
    }

    public void setCallButton(ImageView bCall) {
        this.bCall = bCall;
    }

    public TextView getTvName() {
        return tvName;
    }

    public void setTvName(TextView tvName) {
        this.tvName = tvName;
    }

    public TextView getTvNumber() {
        return tvNumber;
    }

    public void setTvNumber(TextView tvNumber) {
        this.tvNumber = tvNumber;
    }

    public TextView getTvMail() {
        return tvMail;
    }

    public void setTvMail(TextView tvMail) {
        this.tvMail = tvMail;
    }

}

}
```

This is the listView-XML:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
```

And the contact_list_row.XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_background"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bCall"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_clean_phone" />
```

Selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/h_main_button_background_pressed"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/h_main_button_background"></item>

</selector>
```

If you find any other errors or unnecessary code, I'm very thankful for that too!

Comment: put the `imageView` selector code.

Comment: Done, it's at the bottom